# why is `position:relative` computed as `position: static` in devtools for safari and opera?

Tags: html, css, html-table, cross-browser, position

I have created an html table to display an hour-by-hour schedule. In the `<tbody>` tag, I added a `<div>` that draws a horizontal line that represents the current time and is positioned using JS. It's working perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, as the time line is well positioned. But unfortunately it is not working on Opera or Safari.

This problem happens for Safari 12.1.1 and Opera 60.0.3255.170.

Below is an extract of my html:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="hour"></th>

      <th> John Steed </th>
      <th> Emma Peel </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <div class="time"></div>
    <tr>
      <td class="hour">9am</td>
      <td>Somme appointment</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hour">10am</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hour">11am</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Somme appointment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hour">12pm</td>
      <td>Somme appointment</td>
      <td>Somme appointment</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my scss:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;

  tbody {
    position: relative;

    .time {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      height: 1px;
      width: 100%;
      color: #ff5722;
      background-color: #ff5722;

      &:before {
        content: 'Now';
      }

      &.hidden {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    tr {
      height: 109px;

      td {
        border-top: 1px #a8a8a8 dashed;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(2n) {
          background-color: #fafafa;
      }

      &:hover {
        background-color: #ededed;
      }
    }
  }

  th {
    padding: 1rem 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px #a8a8a8 solid;
    position: relative;
  }

  th, td {
    border-left: 1px #a8a8a8 solid;
    border-right: 1px #a8a8a8 solid;
    width: 200px;

    &.hour {
      width: 75px;
      padding-right: 1rem;
      vertical-align: top;
      border: none;
      text-align: right;
    }
  }
}
```

The  positionning is marked as relative in my css, but I've noticed that in the devtools for both Opera and Safari, although it is displayed `relative` in the "Styles" section, in the "Computed" it is actually shown `static`. So my guess is that for some reason, the `position` directive is simply ignored. But the problem is I can't see any reason why... 
Hope you guys have some ideas :)
Thanks !!

Comment: position : relative works nearly as position: static .An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position.

Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position...HTML elements are positioned static by default.

Static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties.

Comment: I guess it has to do with them being table elements. Have you tried it on normal divs or something?

Comment: @user3154108 you seem to be (partially) right... according to W3C (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position): "The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.". So I guess it's up to the browser then :( :( :( :(

Comment: There's a bit more than just that going on, though. Your `.time` div element isn't inside the tbody, (the HTML parser will eject it) so it won't be be absolutely positioned with reference to the tbody in any browser.

Comment: @Alohci, what do you mean by `your .time div element isn't inside the tbody` ? because it is inside the `<tbody>` tag...

Comment: No it isn't. Look at inspect element in your browser's dev tools. If your web page HTML matches the extract you provide above, you'll see that the `.time` div element comes before the entire table. Or you can use [Live Dom Viewer](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/saved/7040)

Comment: The ejected div element also is browser dependend. div elements inside a tbody are semantically faulty, the don't belong into a table structure. Some browsers 'fix' that problem one way or another. You could try wrap the div Element inside a tr or something, but I guess for your purposes a table structure might just be not adequat.

Comment: @user3154108 - No, it really isn't browser dependent. The HTML5 spec requires browsers to move the element to just before the table. The process for doing so even has a name: it's called [foster parenting](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#foster-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers ! I had to find another way around to fix it. Indeed a `div` is faulty as a direct child of a `table` or `tbody` element. So eventually, to make it fully compatible, I had to move it out my `table` and place it in a container.
Now it's working fine !